# 3D Float16 Texture Sizes

Tags: metal

I am rendering Signed Distance Fields into a 3D rgba16Float texture and render the contents of the 3D texture via ray marching.

Right now on my M1 Max the maximum rgba16Float size I can allocate is around 700x700x700, a bit larger and the allocation fails.

In the documentation of Apple the max size of 3D textures is given as 2048.

Now, I have 64gb of unified memory on my M1 Max and would love to be able to create and render larger textures.

Is the limitation I currently experience a hardware limitation ? Or something driver / software related which can one day increase ?

Comment: The only relevant info we're provided that I've found so far is [maxBufferLength](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/2966563-maxbufferlength). My M1 Pro's GPU returns 16 GB. Yours must be at least that high. Your texture is only ≈2.5 GB. Interesting.

Comment: I allocate a few more 8 bit RGBA textures of the same size to hold BSDF material info. Maybe there is a limit on the totally addressable memory space in a shader ? It’s hard to figure out what happens as the allocation does not really fail, just no valid output is rendered.

Comment: Have you tried creating MTLTexture from a heap?

Comment: Via MTLHeap ? No, I will look into it, thanks.

Comment: When you capture the Metal frame, how much memory does it show allocated for your  rgba16Float 700x700x700 texture? Can you post a screen shot of Metal Frame Capture -> Summary -> Show Memory?

Comment: It shows 2.5GB but I have several of them open (to a total of 13.5GB), seems I do not purge existing textures correctly when switching resolutions, I have to do some debugging ...